Is the geometric genus of a Gorenstein variety a birational invariant?
If $X$ is a projective scheme with at worst Gorenstein singularities, then the dualising sheaf ${\omega}_X$ is a line bundle and it makes sense to talk about the geometric genus $p_g(X) := \mathrm h^0(X,\omega_X)$. I was wondering if $p_g$ is a birational invariant, as is for non-singular varieties proved in Hartshorne Theorem II.8.19. The same proof cannot be extended to the singular case as it uses the valuative criterion of properness.
In particular, consider a resolution of singularity $\pi\colon \tilde X \to X$ such that $K_{\tilde X} = \pi^*K_{\tilde X} + \sum_{i}a_iE_i$, where $E_i$ are irreducible exceptional divisors. It seems no reason to expect that $\mathrm h^0(K_X) = \mathrm h^0(K_{\tilde X})$ for the bad cases that some $a_i \ne 0$. If the statement is false, what can we say for those singular varieties whose $p_g$ is the same as their non-singular model?

First you need to assume $X$ is normal, otherwise the normalization is a birational map which will change the plurigenera (e.g. the normalization of a nodal cubic curve by $\mathbb{P}^1$). This is the reason that the geometric genus of a singular curve is defined to be the genus of the normalization rather than $h^0(\omega_X)$.
Let $X$ be a normal variety. We say that $X$ has canonical singularities if $K_X$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-Gorenstein and for any resolution $\mu : X' \to X$, we have
$$
K_{X'} = \mu^*K_X + \sum_{exceptionals} a_i E_i
$$
with $a_i \geq 0$. The numbers $a_i$ are called the discrepancies.
Canonical singularities are the largest class of singularities for which the plurigenera $P_n := H^0(X, \omega_X^{\otimes n})$ are birational invariants. You can find a proof of this statement in these notes of Kollár (Proposition 18).
For an explicit example where this fails, consider the projective cone over a plane quartic curve. The minimal resolution $\mu : X' \to X$ is given by blowing up the cone point. Then $X'$ is a ruled surface so $P_m(X') = 0$ for $m \geq 1$. On the other hand, $X \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ is a quartic so by adjunction, $\omega_X \cong \mathcal{O}_X$ so $P_m(X) = 1$ for all $m \geq 0$.

but adjunction shows $ \omega_X $ is $ \mathcal{O}_X(-1) $

@CraniumClamp oops, thanks! Fixed.
